# How to rollback transaction in Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, transactions

I want to do several inserts in my method, and want to rollback all the inserts if anything goes wrong.
Here's my jdbc bean definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And here's my method

```
@Transactional
public void save(Map<String, String> properties, Long moduleId,
                 String language, String propertyFileName, String filePath) {

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    final String propertyFileQuery = "INSERT INTO property_file " +
            "(moduleId, languageId, propertyFileName,hash,path) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(propertyFileQuery, new String[]{"id"});
        ps.setLong(1, moduleId);
        ps.setString(2, language);
        ps.setString(3, propertyFileName);
        ps.setString(4, "hash goes here");
        ps.setString(5, filePath);

        return ps;
    }, keyHolder);

    int x = 0 / 0;

    final String propertiesQuery = "INSERT INTO property_value " +
            "(propertyFileId, propKey, propValue) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?)";

    properties.forEach((key, value) -> jdbcTemplate.update(
            propertiesQuery, keyHolder.getKey(), key, value
    ));

}
```

I want it to rollback the first insert, after it meets the runtime exception `0/0`

But the data goes into the database, and doesn't get rolled back.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the reason. The transaction management was ok, the reason I couldn't do my job in a transaction was because of my MySQL Engine. It was set to `MyISAM`.
As cited in MySQL web site

> MyISAM does not support transactions and probably never will.

Just changed the tables from `MyISAM` to `InnoDb`, and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the @Transactional to your class instead of binding it with individual methods because when you bind it to a class then all the actions will participate in a single global transaction and if any transaction fails your action will be rolled back

Answer (score 0):

```
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionmanager) {
    this.transactionManager = transactionmanager;
}
```

and inside the method you have to use

```
    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
```

and after `jdbcTemplate.update` you have to commit transaction

```
        transactionManager.commit(status);
```

you can also use `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)`
`